# How to use emmet for Python in Vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How can i use emmet in for python in  Vs code?

[image]

What item and value should I enter to add emmet for python and other languages?

Comment: you need to enter `python` and `html` and you can do it in 2 ways

Answer (score 1):

"[Emmet](https://emmet.io/) is a plug-in for many popular text editors, which can greatly improve the HTML and CSS workflow."

In VSCode, there is no requirement to install this extension. And currently, our use of it in VSCode is more web development related languages, such as "html", "js", etc.

For python, many functions such as auto completion and prompt are provided by [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extensions and its language service.

For the use of "`Item`" and "`Value`" in "`Emmet: Include Languages`", you can refer to:

[image]

[image]

For more information about how to use "emmet" in VSCode, you can refer to:

[Emmet in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)

Answer (score 1):

in `.vscode` folder > `setting.json` add this:

```
{
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "javascript": "javascriptreact",
      "razor": "html",
      "plaintext": "pug",
      "django-html":"html"
  }
}
```

For more info follow this link: [Emmet in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)